# Inner Product Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the vector space of all $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ with the inner product $\langle  A, B \rangle= tr(A B ̄t )$. Find the orthogonal complement of the
subspace of diagonal matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please edit your post using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematical expressions.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried so far? Do you have a guess as to what the answer should be?

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $ \mathcal{D}$ the subspace of diagonal matrices.

Now Let $A \in M_n( \mathbb C)$. Then

$A \in \mathcal{D}^{\perp} \iff tr(AD)=0$  for all $D \in \mathcal{D}$.

For $D=diag(d_1,...,d_n) \in \mathcal{D}$ and $A=(a_{jk})$ we have $tr(AD)= \sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}d_j$.

Can you now show that $A=(a_{jk}) \in \mathcal{D}^{\perp} \iff a_{jj}=0$ for all $j=1,...,n$ ?